# Setting MVC renderParameter for Liferay Search Container

Tags: java, model-view-controller, liferay, liferay-6.2

I'm developing a gallery application, which has two tabs (`<aui:nav>`), both containing a search-container with the same columns, one shows the uploaded images, and the other one is showing the uploaded images by current logged in user id (uploader name, uploaded date, image, etc.).

I have added ordering to both tables, which is working fine on the main (first) tab.

However, if you click the table header to sort it on the second tab, it jumps to the first tab - with the sorting is working THERE. E.g.: I want to sort my uploaded images by upload date, I click it, and it jumps to the first tab, which shows all images, but now sorted by date.

I guess that it goes to the "default" view, like after a portlet action, but I don't know how to override the mvcPath for that sort call?

EDIT: Meanwhile, I removed the tab navigation, that is not the problem's source. Basically I'd just have to set the renderURL of the sorting but I don't know how, so it jumps to the default view of the portlet. More generally:

1.JSP is the default view, and has three columns: A, B, C. Sorting works.
2.JSP is the other view, and also has the same three columns: A, B, C. If sorting by A, 1.JSP is rendered, but sorted by column A. (Same for B and C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out:

First, you have to set a renderURL on the 2.JSP.

```
<%
    PortletURL iteratorUrl = (PortletURL) renderResponse.createRenderURL();
    iteratorUrl.setParameter("mvcPath", "/html/portletname/2.jsp");
%>
```

Then, you add this url to the search-container.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container iteratorURL="<%=iteratorUrl%>" {other parameters}>
```

And now it's rendering the desired page, not the default view (1.JSP).